# As of Jan 2015, does one have to take their shoes off at Toronto Pearson airport's security checkpoints?

Tags: airport-security, yyz

At Toronto Pearson airport do people have to take their shoes off to get through security for international or domestic flights? Is security more careful when travelling to particular countries?

Comment: What made you think there is this new take shoes off security measure?

Comment: @Huangism: Never been through YYZ security but I was curious whether they have upgraded to the shoe scanning mats like some US airports. And, I dress differently if I might have to take my shoes off.  I'm one of those people that is not okay walking around in my socks or feet on a filthy airport floor.  :-)

Comment: As far as I know at Pearson you don't need to take off your shoes unless they detected something and requires you to take off your shoes. I been through there numerous times and never once did I have to take my shoes off. It's more of a US thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly.  It's not every passenger that has to, but you may, if:

1. They ask you to do so, or
2. Your shoes contain metal (eg steel toed/capped shoes)

Source: [Toronto Airport Security Requirements](http://www.torontopearson.com/Departing.aspx#)

Comment: Oh, I thought everyone has to go through...so YYZ hasn't mentioned updating to that mat that scams shoes?

Comment: Boots and high shoes in general often have to be taken off.

Comment: @verve everyone has to go through security, but they won't make you take all footwear off.

Comment: @Mark Mayo: Yes, I know that everyone has to :-)... by chance do flip-flips have to be taken off ever?

Comment: @verve never seen it happen, if they don't have metal, probably not?

Comment: @MarkMayo:  After discovering a show called "Border Security"  I'm totally surprised by how anal security can be.

Comment: @JoErNan0 High shoes as in heels or hi-top sneakers?

Answer (score 1):

Last couple of times I didn't have to, but some others (including a woman they were paying special attention to) did. It may depend on destination- these were not US destinations (Mexico and Canada), so relatively low risk compared to the US or UK.

Comment: So, if you're going to the US it's more strict? Didn't follow you completely...

Comment: Quite possibly, I just don't have any such flights in the last few months to compare.